# Pandas.read_csv with multiple delimiters for lines and versus columns

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to read a csv into a pandas dataframe that separates rows by bracket and columns by commas: "["column1, column2, etc "]". There are also double quotes in the file text. For example this should produce 4 columns and 3 rows.

```
slug,site_id,page_id,page_text
"[""act"", 1, 24, ""Hi, thank you so much for RSVP'ing""]","[""act"", 1, 43, ""Thank you for taking the time to tell us why wireless matters to you!“”]”,"[""uoaa"", 2, 238, ""First published at Oregonlive.com on January 28th, 2019.“”]”
```

The code I'm trying just makes a mess of it, creating 1 row and many columns with wherever there are commas. It is not registering that everything in between the brackets is a single row, and a new set of brackets means its a new row.

```
df = pd.read_csv(tar.extractfile(csv_path), header=0, sep=r'\[|\]|,', quotechar='"',quoting=1, engine = 'python')
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your rows are separated by `\n` in the csv file?

Comment: the rows are separated by a comma.

Answer (score 1):

Rows are separated by `,` and a row is between `"[...]"`:

```
"[""act"", 1, 24, ""Hi, thank you so much for RSVP'ing""]","[""act"", 1, 43, ""Thank you for taking the time to tell us why wireless matters to you!""]"
```

```py
import pandas as pd
import ast
import re

ROWS = re.compile(r'''(\"{1}\[.*\]\"{1}),(\"{1}\[.*\]\"{1})*''')

records = [ast.literal_eval(re.sub(r'"("*)', r'\1', row))
               for row in ROWS.findall(open('data.csv').read())[0]]

df = pd.DataFrame(records)
```

```py
>>> df
     0  1   2                                                  3
0  act  1  24                 Hi, thank you so much for RSVP'ing
1  act  1  43  Thank you for taking the time to tell us why w...

>>> df.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 2 entries, 0 to 1
Data columns (total 4 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype
---  ------  --------------  -----
 0   0       2 non-null      object
 1   1       2 non-null      int64
 2   2       2 non-null      int64
 3   3       2 non-null      object
dtypes: int64(2), object(2)
memory usage: 192.0+ bytes
```

Comment: I ran it but got the following error: 
*** ValueError: malformed node or string: <_ast.Name object at 0x7fd2ecf43c70>

Comment: Ah, the csv does have a , separating lines as well, so in the above example the file looks like ...RSVP'ing""]","[""act"",...

Comment: Therefore, the file contains only one line (no `\n`). I will fix my answer.

Comment: This is getting close, but oddly the first 9 rows got converted into 9 columns containing all four columns in it.  The last row was correctly parsed. I noticed that there are some double spaces in the text, which appears to substituted out for \xa0.

Comment: Index 0, column 0 contains this:  0
0 "['act', 1, 24, ""Thank you so much for RSVP'ing to our Telephone Townhall.\xa0 To add this event to your calendar, please click here.\xa0 If you know anyone who you think would like to join the tele townhall, please click here to send them an email, or send them this link:\xa0 -Sarah from ACT""]"

Comment: \xa0 is actually non-breaking space in Latin1 (ISO 8859-1). I can't do anymore if I don't have the original file.

Comment: Would that break your search criteria? I'm looking at your code and looking at the actual text file to see if I missed something that would break the re.compile. Assuming I'm reading that correctly, it looks right to me and I can't find anything missing. I'm starting to look at the 'records = [ast....'

Comment: The last row is the one that was correctly parsed. Could it be that the comma between rows is throwing off the search criteria? The last row doesn't have at the comma after the "]" which is the only difference I can find.

Comment: So I figured out what's happening. For whatever reason the first x number of rows gets entered into records as tuples and the last row as a list (maybe no comma at end?). records then has two items -- a tuple and a list. If I convert the tuple and list to separate dataframes and then concat them together, it works. If you want to adjust your answer or simply add the code I'll put below I'll accept your answer. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: df1 = pd.DataFrame(records[0])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(records[1]).transpose()
frames = [df1, df2]
df = pd.concat(frames)